# Why is document.getElementsByClassName not working in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, document

So I have this piece of Code

```
const desc_object = document.getElementsByClassName("singlePostDesc");
console.log(desc_object[0]);
```

And this is the JSX

```
{updateMode ? (
                        <>
                            <textarea
                                className="singlePostDescInput"
                                autoFocus={true}
                                id="desc"
                                onChange={(e) => setDesc(e.target.value)}
                                onKeyPress={(e) => key_callback(e.key)}
                            >
                                {desc}
                            </textarea>
                            <button
                                className="singlePostButton"
                                onClick={update_post_to_backend}
                            >
                                Update Post
                            </button>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        <div className="singlePostDesc" id="descThing">
                            <ReactMarkdown children={sanitizeHtml(desc)} />
                        </div>
                    )}
```

But I get the result as `undefined`. Why? Is it because it is wrapped in a ternary operator? I am using React JS.

Comment: When you're using React, you're not meant to use the DOM directly.

Comment: Firstly, ideally don't use vanilla JS DOM stuff when using React. Secondly, if it's conditionally rendered then it will only be in the DOM based on the condition. Without seeing what `updateMode` is initially, at what point you're trying to access the DOM element etc. we can't really give much more info

Comment: @Jayce444 I access the element on ```useEffect```, right when the webpage is loaded. ```updateMode``` is set as false on default, so the element gets loaded on the first render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to access DOM methods in react, you have to call this piece of code inside `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const desc_object = document.getElementsByClassName("singlePostDesc");
  if (desc_object) {
   // now you can access it here
  }

})
```

though the first time `useEffect` hooks runs `getElementsByClassName` will return `undefined` because the DOM is not mounted yet.

if you want to run this DOM query only after the component did mount, you can create a custom hook:

```
const useDidMountEffect = (func, deps) => {
 const didMount = useRef(false)

 useEffect(() => {
   if (didMount.current) func()
   else didMount.current = true
  }, deps)
}
```

and then you can use it like that:

```
useDidMountEffect (() => {
 const desc_object = document.getElementsByClassName("singlePostDesc");


})
```

UPDATE:

as comments mentioned, ideally you should not use vanilla js, you should use [React Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)